# Optional arguments: xparse vs. xargs

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, xparse

To implement a macro that takes one or more optional arguments that do not have to be placed in the first position, `xargs` can be used as well as `xparse`. The latter seems to have more recent updates while the first uses the well-known keyval internally.

Apart from this and their syntax, where do they differ? Can one of them be regarded as superior or deprecated? Is there a guideline which to use in new documents?

Comment: Both packages are stable and can be used. So it's your choice which fits your needs more.

Comment: `xargs` (as far as I can tell) can't (easily) distinguish between the cases when the optional argument is missing or present. Moreover it hasn't the possibility of defining *-variants or arguments with different delimiters than braces and brackets.

Answer (score 8):

With `xargs` you're limited to pass a default value to optional arguments, so it's not easy to distinguish when the argument is missing. Conversely, `xparse` provides `\IFNoValueTF` just for this case.

For instance, one can say

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {foo without optional argument}
    {foo with optional argument #1}%
}
```

With `xparse` you can also define `*`-variants of commands and also commands taking arguments delimited in various ways. Arguments can be “long” on an individual basis, while with `xargs` either all are “long” or none is. An example of `*`-variant is the following command that has the same syntax as `\section`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{ s o m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {*-variant called, do something with #3}
    {%
     \IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {normal foo without optional argument, do something with #3}
      {normal foo with optional argument, do something with #2 and #3}%
    }%
 }
```

So `\foo*{Xyz}`, `\foo{Xyz}` or `\foo[Abc]{Xyz}` are the possible calls. Actually also `\foo*[Abc]{Xyz}` is allowed, but with the code above, argument `#2` would be ignored.